# Fastest method of leveling 50-60?

Tags: rift

As the title says, what gives the most experience in Rift for Storm Legion leveling? I'm currently at level 56 and would like to reach level 60 prior to the Autumn Harvest event that starts later this week. So far my main method of leveling has been running instant adventures, however I'm not sure if specific dungeons, rift hunts, pvp, etc will give more experience at a faster rate.

Does anyone know what the fastest possible method to level in game is? I know that there are people who can go 1-60 in a single weekend so I know that it's possible to go 56-60 in a matter of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to level is to try to stick to the quest line in Storm Legion in my honest opinion, as it does offer a great amount of XP ( & great story too!).

But Here is a great video to follow and gather tips from as well:

Comment: Would you happen to know how that compares to just doing instant adventures by any chance? I've kinda ignored the entire quest storyline so far in the game.

Comment: Not exact numbers as there a lottttt of different factors that play in to that (% success rate in instances, number of team members, speed of kills, wipe rate, group DPS, etc).  XP/hour questing is the most reliable and fastest way to level instead of grinding as you aren't *always* relying on someone else.  I have read that it should take roughly between 5-8 hours per level from 56-60 from various sources when you quest.

Comment: @Valrok you don't get that much exp from IA + you got some nice rep + not bad equipment from the questline. Also it's nice to have all porticullums activated in the areas. Btw it's also recommended to switch between the both islands to get more from the leveling + should be faster.